# How to correctly retrieve modifier keys in a WPF KeyDown event?

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I've seen a number of answers suggesting the use of `Keyboard.Modifiers` to determine whether a `KeyDown` event is for a key that had a modifier set. Unfortunately, because `Keyboard.Modifiers` returns the *current* state of the modifiers (instead of the state of the modifier when the key was pressed), this results in a really annoying intermittent bug for quick typists.

Specifically, imagine someone presses Ctrl+A, and releases Ctrl only a few milliseconds after pressing A. Now imagine that the system was under heavy load; the key handler started executing but was preempted for 50ms. By the time the key handler is executing again, the *current* state of Ctrl is "released". The key handler will now think that "A" was pressed without Ctrl, and this is *bad*.

Similarly, if a fast typist enters A, Ctrl+End and my application uses `Keyboard.Modifiers`, it could instead end up observing Ctrl+A...

In WinForms, the `KeyDown` event tells me the state of Ctrl *exactly*, even if it's already released by the time the event is being handled. How can I get this same behaviour in WPF?

**Edit**: it's possible that Keyboard.Modifiers doesn't actually retrieve the "current" modifier keys, but instead the modifier keys as related to the key down message currently being processed. In WinAPI, this was the distinction between "async" and non-async key state functions. Unfortunately, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx) doesn't mention what exactly "current" means. If anyone knows, please say so.

Comment: are you sure? 
i don't find any hint on msdn, that will proof your theory...
it would be really strange, that the handler-arguments does not include the ORIGINALLY pressed keys...
if you bind to "onkeyDown" and the user presses CONTROL (hold) and then a, then releases CONTROL, the event will be fired 2 times!

first with "Control" only, then with CONTROL+A...

a little bit of strange -- imho, we could figure that easily out with thread.sleep ...

do i have to boot up VS right now? ;)

Comment: @TheHe The handler arguments include the originally pressed _key_, but not the modifier key information. In the good old WinAPI, the modifier keys are passed along with the message. The same happens in WinForms. The documentation actually warns you not to try and process the _current_ state; for example, if the application was unresponsive for any reason (e.g. HDD thrashing), the handler may be invoked _seconds_ after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

As there does not appear to be any modifier information in the event args you could keep track of the state yourself in some fields and handling both `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` to update them accordingly.

e.g.

```
private bool ctrl = false;
private void This_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl) //or switch, also: `LeftCtrl` & `RightCtrl` are treated as separate keys
        ctrl = true;
    //etc..
}

private void This_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
        ctrl = false;
    //etc..
}
```

Whether this is actually a good idea i cannot say...

---

If you want to handle key gestures i would suggest using dedicated methods like [`KeyBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) they should only fire when the gesture happened. For other input you may also want to have a look at [`TextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput.aspx) which is more abstract and returns the text that the input is translated to.

Answer (score 2):

sorry for this destructive answer but...

after a little bit of research it becomes clear to me...
the event is called "KeyDown" not "KeyCombinationDown" so it is totally independent of any Modifiers pressed BEFORE...

Actually there is a right way for achieve your goal:
Using the Commanding-Pattern.

You define a COMMAND (see google for WPF-Commanding) and add a KeyBinding to your application, where you define the key or the keys/key-combination which will fire up the command...

See the example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx

IMHO, this is the *only* way and semantically more elegant, too.

(if this pattern will not be working for you in GENERAL, you maybe have to use native api with pinvoke).

cheers.

Comment: I don't see this as destructive. You suggest an alternative, after all. It's just that if you google around, you'll only see "use Keyboard.Modifiers", hence this question...

Comment: Unfortunately this has a side effect (bug?): When the key binding matches, the key down event is *always* marked as handled, even if the command cannot execute. So in that case the key press will never be translated to a TextInput.