# How to make a RichTextBox stop consuming key gestures

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

The RichTextBox provides a [lot of commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with accompanying key gestures.

However, when `IsReadOnly=True` is set, many of those commands do not make sense and do not take any action, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Nevertheless, when a command in the Window uses one of the key gestures, the command in the Window does not fire when the RichtTextBox has focus:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:MainWindow.MyCommand" Executed="MyCommandBinding_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox Height="50" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <CheckBox Content="This is a checkbox" />
    <TextBlock Name="whatsGoingOn" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static RoutedUICommand MyCommand = new RoutedUICommand(
        "My Command",
        "MyCommand",
        typeof(MainWindow),
        new InputGestureCollection() { new KeyGesture(Key.R, ModifierKeys.Control) });

    private void MyCommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        whatsGoingOn.Text += ".";
    }
}
```

Now maybe the right answer is “don’t use RichTextBox with `IsReadOnly="True"`, use something else instead”, but let’s assume I had to or wanted to use RichTextBox.

What can I do to make key gestures fire my command even when the RichTextBox has focus?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the keystrokes in the PreviewKeyDown event of the RichTextBox. Set the e.Handled member to true and that will prevent the actually processing of the keys.

Hope it helps

Comment: Intercepting PreviewKeyDown or overriding OnPreviewKeyDown in a derived class does not make the command fire. Of course, I could call `MyCommand_Executed` manually, but then I don’t need to use a command in the first place. Moreover, interceptiong a key stroke this way is a bit hackish for the reason mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125590/how-to-correctly-retrieve-modifier-keys-in-a-wpf-keydown-event. Sorry, but I’m not convinced :)